# Swiper.js does not react like in the documentation

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, swiper.js

I'm trying to use Swiper.js (http://idangero.us/swiper/api/) but it act really strangely when i add it to my project even if i disable all my other JS files. For example if i use the autoplay function this way:

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                autoplay: 2500,
            });
```

It works fine, but if i get fancy like this (like in the docs) :

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
          autoplay: {
              delay: 2500,
          },
        });
```

The slider start autoplaying without delay even if i change it.
I cant get the navigation buttons to work too, they are there but nothing happens when i click on them:

```
<div class="swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 1</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 2</div>
        <div class="swiper-slide">Slide 3</div>
    </div>
    <!-- Add Pagination -->
    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
    <!-- Add Arrows -->
    <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
</div>
<script>
    var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
        navigation: {
            nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
            prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
        },
    });
</script>
```

What have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution for my next and previous buttons after trying for a long time, since nothing have worked, i did a work around like this :

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
                        autoplay: 5000,
                        allowTouchMove : true,
                        parallax: true
                    });

        var mySwiper = document.querySelector('.swiper-container').swiper;

        $('.swiper-button-next').click(function(){
            mySwiper.slideNext();
        });
        $('.swiper-button-prev').click(function(){
            mySwiper.slidePrev();
        });
```

Maybe it will help another personne that have the same problem as me.